# Is Apache Ignite suited for NoSQL schema

Tags: json, ignite

Is JSON within a JSON supported within Apache Ignite?
Example:

```
{ 
    "stuff": {
        "onetype": [
            {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
            {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
        ],
        "othertype": {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    }, 
    "otherstuff": {
        "thing": [[1,42],[2,2]]
     }
}
```

Goal is being able to query based on any field in a JSON. So far with Apache Ignite I have seen that with creating a class and then storing object of it - is possible to add indexes and query json on a first level of Key/Value pairs but did not see any example for a nested JSON.

Is it maybe better to use MongoDB or Cassandra for that kind of need (to index and query any nested field within a JSON)?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is treated as a regular string when it's put into a cache.
When a JSON has only a single level, then it's possible to represent it as either POJO or BinaryObject, put it into a cache and benefit from all the querying capabilities, but nested objects cannot be indexed and queried properly so far.
As an option, you could use [ScanQueries](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#scan-queries)

Comment: However, it seems that there is no way to sort the results with ScanQueries. You can only sort when using Apache Ignite's SQL queries, which you can't use with the hierarchical structure that is being discussed here. Seems like Apache Ignite cannot truly be used as a NoSQL database like MongoDB.